# Facebook Messenger Verify X-Hub-Signature of Shared Location

Tags: facebook, security, postback, sha, facebook-messenger

I'm adding X-Hub verification to my messenger app. I learned about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference

I've successfully gotten verification to work with simple text messages, but when I send a location instead of a text message, verification fails because the hash I generate and the hash Facebook gives me in the header do not match. Here is my verification code:

```
module.exports.requestIsValid = function(event) {
    if (event['headers']['X-Hub-Signature']) {
        var sha     = event['headers']['X-Hub-Signature']
        var body    = JSON.stringify(event.body);
        return sha == `sha1=${crypto.createHmac('sha1', config.APP_SECRET).update(body).digest('hex')}`;
    }

    return false;   // this return is never called, I know that the first return is the one returning false when it should be true
 }
```

Here is an example of a regular text message payload:

```
{"body":{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"1366222643461024","time":1499114399253,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"1582085681843981"},"recipient":{"id":"1366222643461024"},"timestamp":1499114399084,"message":{"mid":"mid.$cAASAZhi0_wRjO3OtbFdCi5lV2qe4","seq":52192,"text":"Test"}}]}]},"method":"POST","principalId":"offlineContext_authorizer_principalId","headers":{"X-Real-Ip":"173.252.88.182","X-Forwarded-For":"173.252.88.182","Host":"test.localtunnel.me","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https","X-Nginx-Proxy":"true","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"270","Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"deflate, gzip","Content-Type":"application/json","X-Hub-Signature":"sha1=0f51d788fe5f1111846097ad016728cdcd06029f"},"query":{},"path":{},"identity":{"accountId":"offlineContext_accountId","apiKey":"offlineContext_apiKey","caller":"offlineContext_caller","cognitoAuthenticationProvider":"offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationProvider","cognitoAuthenticationType":"offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationType","sourceIp":"127.0.0.1","user":"offlineContext_user","userAgent":"","userArn":"offlineContext_userArn"},"stageVariables":{},"isOffline":true}
```

And here is an example of a payload with a location:

```
{"body":{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"1366222643461024","time":1499114451619,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"1582085681843981"},"recipient":{"id":"1366222643461024"},"timestamp":1499114451469,"message":{"mid":"mid.$cAASAZhi0_wRjO3R6DVdCi8v9yqk0","seq":52196,"attachments":[{"title":"Brandon's Location","url":"https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fmaps%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fv%3D2%26pc%3DFACEBK%26mid%3D8100%26where1%3D35.142236316764%252C%2B-106.53531087607%26FORM%3DFBKPL1%26mkt%3Den-US&h=ATOu8uYrLDiFl6wG8RVfhXvwkMl7uB_l2MHqB_uKLhk8qC9p1ua0EOLpGkznVX7Y8YfxSXP7vDuAR7swPmDCw1esH2bwKhNNsZKxVPC2ViC2AFMO_g&s=1&enc=AZMYxff8btvCZWHtzUR4oFL7K2Mg6nXM_O_tRXXL-L8z508UAOauiSRztoRvWdlGCWU1dNRdNK1ls2CGulM8lvzR","type":"location","payload":{"coordinates":{"lat":35.142236316764,"long":-106.53531087607}}}]}}]}]},"method":"POST","principalId":"offlineContext_authorizer_principalId","headers":{"X-Real-Ip":"173.252.90.239","X-Forwarded-For":"173.252.90.239","Host":"test.localtunnel.me","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https","X-Nginx-Proxy":"true","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"911","Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"deflate, gzip","Content-Type":"application/json","X-Hub-Signature":"sha1=34f23436b2744b9b0cc8776922e7386c454786db"},"query":{},"path":{},"identity":{"accountId":"offlineContext_accountId","apiKey":"offlineContext_apiKey","caller":"offlineContext_caller","cognitoAuthenticationProvider":"offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationProvider","cognitoAuthenticationType":"offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationType","sourceIp":"127.0.0.1","user":"offlineContext_user","userAgent":"","userArn":"offlineContext_userArn"},"stageVariables":{},"isOffline":true}
```

Happy to provide extra info if needed.

UPDATE:
Upon furthere inspection it appears that the verifcation only fails when there is an "attatchments" field in the payload. So if also fails when I send a picture or gif or something like that.

Comment: You should not stringify the data yourself (even the tiniest difference would make the hash invalid), but rather create the hash from the raw post body your application received in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe When I leave out the stringify I get this error -  TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer. Looks like it is coming from the crypto node module I'm using

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the SHA1 algorithm to the 'raw request body'. If you parse body and convert it back to json; it may not work.

Comment: If you want to debug Facebook webhook request as is, you can use chatbotproxy.com

Comment: Ok that makes sense, unfortunately, when I leave out the stringify I get this error -  TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer. Looks like it is coming from the crypto node module I'm using

Comment: You can stringify it. It will work. If you don't stringify and sent it to crypto it will throw that error. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `bodyParserJSON` should return **rawBody**:

```
bodyParser.json({
    verify(req, res, buf) {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
})
```

Here is a middleware that I've written. It uses `crypto` module to generate `sha1`

```
fbWebhookAuth: (req, res, next) => {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.FB_APP_SECRET);
    hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf-8');
    if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === `sha1=${hmac.digest('hex')}`) next();
    else res.status(400).send('Invalid signature');
}
```

and finally in your route you can use it as:

```
app.post('/webhook/facebook', middlewares.fbWebhookAuth, facebook.webhook);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **express** js

```
app.use(express.json({
verify:(req, res, buf)=>{
  req.rawBody = buf;
}}))
```

your middleware

```
const fbWebhookAuth = (req, res, next) => {
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.FB_APP_SECRET);
hmac.update(req.rawBody);
if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === `sha1=${hmac.digest('hex')}`) next();
else res.status(400).send('Invalid signature'); }
```

your endpoint

```
app.post('/webhook/Facebook', fbWebhookAuth, facebook.webhook);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now facebook uses `sha256` Hmac

To verify against them, follow this

A. make your body parser return the raw body as well:

```
webapi.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: function (req, res, buf, encoding) {
        req.rawBody = buf;
    }
}));
```

B.

```
fbVerify = (req, res, next) => {
    req.isXHubValid = false;
    try {
        if (req.headers['x-hub-signature-256']) {
            let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', proccess.env.fbAppSecret);
            hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf-8');
            if (req.headers['x-hub-signature-256'] === `sha256=${hmac.digest('hex')}`)
                req.isXHubValid = true;
        } else if (req.headers['x-hub-signature']) { // leave it for backward compatibility
            let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', proccess.env.fbAppSecret);
            hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf-8');
            if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === `sha1=${hmac.digest('hex')}`)
                req.isXHubValid = true;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    next();
}
```

C. in your webhook function

```
app.post('/webhook/facebook', fbVerify, (req, res) = > {
    if (!req.isXHubValid) {
        return res.sendStatus(404);
    }
    // continue here, the request is valid
});
```